# Updating/Changing huge table in access via vba

Tags: database, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I imported a table into access via vba as dao. Now I need to run a couple of replacements and updates of some table values.

This includes:
- mapping/replacement of Strings (i.e., replace all "ABB" with "Read-Only", "AAB" with "Write", etc.)
- remove leading Strings (i.e. cut leading "_customname")

As I have to work with a HUGE table, I am in need of the fastest approach:

- Should I run simple update queries within VBA?
- Should I go for a line-by-line approach with an "if then apprach"?
- Should I already change the value during the import process?

Or is there a better solution after all?

Comment: The fastest approach is almost certainly going to be SQL.

Comment: and normalise as you go...

Comment: or forget the SQL and just find/replace function since it's just a one time thing.  The leading strings might need a "trim" though so you'd use update query for that.